# Tools to convert asp.net dynamic site into static site

Tags: asp.net, web-crawler

Are there any tools that will spider an asp.net website and create a static site?

Comment: not sure why this has been downvoted... Guess the world was not ready for this in 2008 :) Upvote from me, I would love a "build" that will produces static HTML from an ASP.NET project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.httrack.com/
Have used for this purpose a few times, may need to do a little tidying up of urls, and some css linked images might not make it, depends on how good a job you want to do.
If you have dreamweaver, you can use that to manage the links if you need to clean up the file names afterwards.
Optionally use the link checker extension for firefox to check it all afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You could use OfflineExplorer: http://www.metaproducts.com/mp/Offline_Explorer.htm

This works well as long as you only have GET requests (links). Postbacks will not 
be executed. 
Be aware that crawling your site might acually change the underlying 
database so I would strongly recommend you back up the database and web before 
using a crawler.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is [wget](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Web-Services/Website-Mirroring-With-wget/1/).

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with [WebZip](http://www.spidersoft.com/webzip/screenshots.asp).